# adding boundaries to gamma distribution density

Tags: r

Is there any other elements in `dgamma` other than these?

```
dgamma(x, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE)
```

for example: lower/upper boundary etc

Comment: Gamma is a continuous distribution with support for all umbers greater than zero. What would lower and upper be? Do you want to sample from some other distribution other than gamma? All the parameters that `dgamma` has are documents in the `?dgamma` help page. There are no secret ones.

Comment: yes, I want to sample from other distribution (normal and lognormal)

Comment: @MissZahrah Then your question is really unclear.

Comment: Then there are the `dnorm` and `dlnorm` functions for the normal and lognormal respectively. I don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I just want to know if possible to add any other parameter to 'dgamma'. Now I got the point, thanks to @MrFlick for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any options for setting lower and upper boundaries for dgamma, however in general, you could write a function to scale your distribution as follows:

```
scale <- function(dist){(dist-min(dist))/(max(dist)-min(dist))*(upper-lower)+lower}
```

Where dist is your distribution (dist <- dgamma(...)), upper and lower are the desired upper and lower boundaries of the distribution, consequently. Just, be aware that although the general shape of the distribution is conserved, it statistical properties may change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a truncated gamma distribution then just divide `dgamma` (in the range specified) by the difference between the pgamma values at the ends of the truncation limits.

```
 dgamma.trunc <- function(x, ..., lower=0, upper=Inf){if( x < lower|| x > upper){0} else {
                   dgamma(x, ...)/( pgamma(upper, ...)-pgamma(lower, ...) )}   }
```